# Parsing leaderboard data from Firebase, using swiftyJSON/swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, swifty-json

I am trying to pull leaderboard data from Firebase. I am able to get the data in proper order when I look at the "snapshot" data. Once I get to the line with var json = JSON(snapshot.value) , the data loses its order.

I am trying to parse the data into swift obects, so that they can be used/displayed in my swift app as an ordered leaderboard. I can find a workaround for my data being out of order pretty easily, but its bothering me.

```
func getScoresData() {
    let scoresRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("/High Scores")

    scoresRef.queryLimitedToFirst(10).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
        var json = JSON(snapshot.value)
        print(json)

        let theKeys = json.dictionary!.keys

        for key in theKeys {

            self.timeStampArray.append(key)

            let tempName = json[key]["Name"]
            self.namesArray.append(String(tempName))

            let tempScore = json[key]["Score"]
            self.scoresArray.append(String(tempScore))
        }
    })
}
```

This is my properly ordered output from the print(snapshot) :

```
Snap (High Scores) {
    "-KC3MktE1jS5z9-tTEgJ" =     {
        ".priority" = "-9";
        Date = "1457140993.669797";
        Name = brendan;
        Score = 9;
        UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
    };
"-KC3MktM-rWmoitem8na" =     {
    ".priority" = "-9";
    Date = "1457140993.677347";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 9;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3MktW0iJfkAKjlCy4" =     {
    ".priority" = "-9";
    Date = "1457140993.686348";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 9;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3MktapH6Mebw2sAUe" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457140993.692581";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3MktbOyltGaJZ_XtD" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457140993.694163";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3MktjFj6VVAJfitZp" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457140993.701368";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3Mktk0_f6_eM8wP1x" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457140993.702492";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3MktrZaStt9b5pID_" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457140993.709843";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3QALPl38gbDy4xLE2" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457141888.477473";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
"-KC3qGAqZiJ9Vs40MwG7" =     {
    ".priority" = "-10";
    Date = "1457148990.24583";
    Name = brendan;
    Score = 10;
    UUID = "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61";
};
```

}

Here is my improperly ordered data from the print(json) line :

```
{
  "-KC3MktrZaStt9b5pID_" : {
    "Score" : "10",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.709843,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3QALPl38gbDy4xLE2" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457141888.477473,
"Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3MktW0iJfkAKjlCy4" : {
    "Score" : "9",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.686348,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3MktbOyltGaJZ_XtD" : {
    "Score" : "10",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.694163,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3Mktk0_f6_eM8wP1x" : {
    "Score" : "10",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.702492,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3MktM-rWmoitem8na" : {
    "Score" : "9",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.677347,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3MktapH6Mebw2sAUe" : {
    "Score" : "10",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.692581,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3qGAqZiJ9Vs40MwG7" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457148990.24583,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3MktjFj6VVAJfitZp" : {
    "Score" : "10",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.701368,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3MktE1jS5z9-tTEgJ" : {
    "Score" : "9",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.669797,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  }
}
```

Since I am using the json object to get the keys, and thus fill the arrays, the data is out of order in the arrays.

What am I missing?

Comment: JSON dictionaries keys are not ordered. Could that be the problem?

Comment: A couple of things here. Firebase's concept of order is defined by you; you need a key to let Firebase know how to order the data when it's read in. If you are wanting an order that is chronological then .orderBy timestamp. If you want to order by score, then .orderBy score. Don't assume your firebase data will be ordered - they may be ordered by key, but that may not be what you want. To answer the question correctly, define how you want your data ordered and we'll show you how to make that happen.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to maintain ordering, use arrays instead of dictionaries, whether it be `JSON` or Swift objects. So to maintain ordering, you could change your `JSON` structure from this:

```
{
  "-KC3MktrZaStt9b5pID_" : {
    "Score" : "10",
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457140993.709843,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  },
  "-KC3QALPl38gbDy4xLE2" : {
    "Score" : 10,
    "UUID" : "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date" : 1457141888.477473,
    "Name" : "brendan"
  }
}
```

to this:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "-KC3MktrZaStt9b5pID_",
    "Score": "10",
    "UUID": "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date": 1457140993.709843,
    "Name": "brendan"
  },
  {
    "Key": "-KC3QALPl38gbDy4xLE2",
    "Score": 10,
    "UUID": "BD561F1C-72A8-4A01-A71A-850682E49D61",
    "Date": 1457141888.477473,
    "Name": "brendan"
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't think Firebase supports arrays natively, as per : https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Ok, then keep your old syntax. The part in the blog about using priorities to order your data might be handy dictionaries are inherently not ordered.

Comment: @jakhamma NSArray's are definitely supported in Firebase. However, a majority of the time there are better solutions than using arrays to store your data. Array's can be... problematic and should only be used in specific situations, and even then there are usually better options.